# regex to exclude 2 consecutive variations

Tags: regex, r, fuzzy-comparison

I am trying to do some fuzzy matching (in R) and want to make some rules about how many consecutive variations are allowed. For example, if I use the Levenshtein Distance and the distance is greater than 2, I want to exclude any matches where these 2 variations happen next to each other.

An example:

If we are trying to match against the string "James Madison",

-"Jame Madisan" would produce a match with distance=2

-"Jans Madison" would also have distance=2 but would not produce a hit because of the 2 consecutive variations ("n" needs to be changed to "m" and an "e" must be inserted before the "s" in "James")

Comment: How about some possible examples and your attempts?

Comment: I would have to say regex is not the right tool for this task.

Comment: @hwnd Ah, ok. Sorry for the lack of attempts. I do not know any regex and was looking into getting this done with q-grams or from a stringdist matrix from a levenshtein distance calculation but regex seemed like it would be the tool.

Comment: Post a real example (using R code or dput-output)  if you are unable to find answer after more "homework"-effort. There are implementations of Levenshtein distance functions and you could use `rollapply` from pkg:zoo to pass it over a vector of character items.